# how to change the authentication table used by jwt-auth in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

as you see in the title,when i using tymondesigns/jwt-auth to authenticate the HTTP requests, i generated the token with a record of table user,and then when i authenticate the request,i found that the action of 'authenticate' to find a record at the table 'users' that's not i want.

here is the query sql:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 0.39
  ]
]
```

so,my question is:
how to set up the table i want when i do things both generate a token and authenticate, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in their wiki [page](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Configuration#user-model-path---user), you can use "user" option to specify the Model name which you want to use in `config/jwt.php`.

> User model path - user
>
> This should be the namespace path that points to your User class.